# AOSP lldbclient.py missing?

Tags: debugging, native, android-source, lldb

I'm building AOSP from source and have created a small C++ program that prints some messages to `logcat` when started. Now I wanted to debug the program according to https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/gdb

In the reference you're encouraged to use `lldb` in favor of `gdb` and there is also a short section on using vs code as debugger.

However, I cannot find the mentioned script `lldbclient` anywhere in my source nor in Android Code Search, only `gdbclient.py` seems to be present.

**Q1: Where can I find lldbclient script?**

When running the `gdbclient.py` script the option `--setup-forwarding vscode` seems to be ignored and `gdb` is always started.

**Q2: If there isn't a `lldbclient` script, what options do I have to pass to `gdbclient.py` to enable debugging with `lldb` and vs code?**

**What did I do so far?**

```
gdbclient.py -r /data/mysample_bin --setup-forwarding vscode
```

Starts my native program with attached `gdb` and allows me to step through my program.

Though I do not know how to code python, I was able to track down a call sequence in the script to method `generate_setup_script`, which is called with parameter `debugger=gdb`. Therefore no `lldb` configuration for vs code is created. Passing `--no-gdb` or `--lldb` to the script doesn't change this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: You can find lldbclient.py script in the repository https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development, branch android-s-beta-2 (or another android-s branch).
Q2: Android also provides some tutorial debugging with Vscode: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/gdb#vscode.